# rails 5 api app jsonapi CollectionSerializer type override on serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, types, json-api

Using the jsonapi serialization as the default serialization type, does anyone know how to get the collection type included when serializing the collection?

I've tried specifying a custom serializer for the resource and overriding the type, but I get an error

### NoMethodError (undefined method `type' for UsersSerializer:Class):

```
class UsersSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer
   type 'users'
end
```

or

```
class UsersSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer  
  def json_key
    "users"
  end
end
```

the last one doesn't throw an error but also doesn't emit the type

the output I'd like to have is one consistent with the jsonapi with a type property on the returned object. i.e.

```
{
    "type": "users",
    "data": [{user}{user}{user}]
}
```

what I am currently getting is

```
{
    "data: [{user},{user},{user}]
}
```

when I call the following from my controller

```
render json: @users, serializer: UsersSerializer, each_serializer: UserSerializer
```

or

```
render json: @users, serializer: UsersSerializer, :root='users', each_serializer: UserSerializer
```

or

```
render json: @users, serializer: UsersSerializer, json_key='users' each_serializer: UserSerializer
```

I know what I am trying to do is probably simple, but searching for 'ruby rails 5 api app jsonapi CollectionSerializer type' turns up a slew of information unrelated to what I am trying to accomplish.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After additional research, the 'type' attribute is not part of the json-api spec at the root. Instead, I have opted to use the 'meta' attribute on the top level collection type. i.e.

```
 render json: @users, serializer: UsersSerializer, :meta=>{:type=>"users"}, each_serializer: UserSerializer
```